# How can i solve the Binary Text Classification Problem

Tags: python, security, svm, text-classification, bert-language-model

For my master thesis i'm developing a system to classify and extract cybersecurity countermeasures from unstructured texts.
In my binary classifier I want to check if a text is relevant or not. For this purpose I tried two approaches:

1. Scikit-Learn Support Vector Machines:

- I used the paper by Husari et al. as a guide https://www.researchgate.net/publication/321503662_TTPDrill_Automatic_and_Accurate_Extraction_of_Threat_Actions_from_Unstructured_Text_of_CTI_Sources.
- They used three features for their svm classifier
- My Question: How can I add Features to SVM classifier?

2. BERT with pytorch

- I created a dataset with manually labeled texts (100; 30 relevant; 70 not relevant)
- Output 70 % accuracy and 61 % loss seems not good enough
- I think it's because of the small dataset
- My Question: Is there another possibility to use BERT with small datasets to get more accurate results?

Comment: This is a design question, please ask non-programming questions on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/. There are several problems here: first the paper you mention is quite complex and doesn't only do text classification; also it doesn't use only 3 features. "adding features" to SVM -> do you mean that you don't know how to generate the features? The 70% accuracy corresponds to 70% non relevant, it's likely that all the documents are predicted as the majority class, i.e. there is an error somewhere.

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. Yes I know that the paper do not only text classification but I oriented on their classification approach. I have extracted 3 features: the term frequency, the length of the texts (count word tokens) and a check if the text has included Indicator of Compromise. Now I don't know how to put them together in one classifier (e.g. sklearn.svm.svc). Is this possible or do I have to build my own classifier with this three features? To the Bert approach: Yes I think there are some errors because of the dataset.

Comment: I think that the source of the problem is that you have a confusion about the features: you cannot expect good results with only 3 features in text classification, usually the features represent the vocabulary (or a subset of it). Anyway if you have a feature 'term frequency' I assume that you have it for multiple terms, right? If so you have at least N features where N is the number of terms. Once you have clearly defined your features, you just create an array containing exactly these features for every instance. This is what you feed to SVM (or any other supervised algorithm).

Comment: Yes right. I apologize for my english. By features I mean the individual components that a "relevant" text must have: Vocabulary, text length and IOCs. So I wrote a tfidfvectorizer and a svm classifier and trained it. But it only checks the vocabular. I want to put the three "components" together, weight them and check a threshhold. For this purpose I have to write my own classifier class. Am I right?

Comment: No you don't need to write your own class, you can simply add features to the vocabulary ones. this might not always work very well with SVM because SVM expects features on the same scale. A decision tree is more capable of handling heterogeneous features in general.

Comment: Can you tell me how I can add this features. In the moment I have one ndarray from the tfidfvectorizer. The other two features contain a binary value (1 or 0) for every text.  How can I create a combination of this three heterogeneous features.

Comment: your ndarray has two dimensions, the first is the instances and the second is the features. i.e. `feature[i][j]` is the feature `j` for instance `i`. for every instance `i` you can append the two additional features to the array. I don't use numpy so I don't know which function you should use, there's probably a simple way to do that. You should also stop calling these your "3 features", it's confusing and incorrect: the text is not one feature, it's a set of multiple features. If you're confused with this I'd suggest you start by doing basic text classification before this more advanced task.